# MYSQL DELETE INNER JOIN only shows deletes after page reload

Tags: html, mysql

I have managed to get working a Duplicate field Check using INNER JOIN with PHP MYSQL , however the delete only shows after a page reload , the 1st time i load the page the duplicate entry's are shown then i reload the page and the DELETES are no longer showing. i dont understand why, does this code show any reason for this to happen?  a page refresh does not happen no matter what code i use, nothing is run during the IF ($RowsDC >1) check other than the DELETE statement

here is the code:

```
while($row = $stat->fetch()){

                            //checking for duplicates

                            try {
                                $db2 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classifieds2", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this
                                $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                                    $queryDC="SELECT * FROM listings WHERE listID = ? AND UID = ? ";

                                        $statDC=$db2->prepare($queryDC);
                                        $statDC->execute(array("$listID","$UID"));

                                            $ResultDC = $statDC->fetchAll();
                                            $RowsDC = count($ResultDC);

                                                if ($RowsDC >1){                                                            $db2A = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classifieds2", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this
                                                                    $db2A->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                                                    $query01DC="DELETE a FROM listings a INNER JOIN listings a2 WHERE a.id < a2.id AND a.listID = a2.listID ";

                                                                    $stat01DC=$db2A->prepare($query01DC);

                                                                    $stat01DC->execute();   

                                                            ??? here i have tried to refresh the page but it does not no matter how i try nothing is run ???

                                                                }

                            }
                            catch (PDOException $e){
                            $_SESSION['message']="Database Error #vbmDUPCHECK2    <br> <h6><h6>Signed Out For Security Reasons</h6></h6>";
                            $_SESSION['loggedin']='000';
                            echo $errorcall;
                            die();
                            exit();
                        }

}//WHILE END
```

Comment: i have trie a php page refresh but this does nothing. the refresh is not even run, i dont get it. the delete runs but not the page refresh afterwards, iv tried doing a header call also , nothing seems to run after the delete , but the delete takes effect?? the fields are deleted in the 1st instance also, but a page refresh is required to show the new database.. any ideas???

Comment: FOUND A SOLUTION, i had to move the Duplicates check before the while loop query as the while loop query was also displaying the data onto the page , so i moved the duplicates check before the while loop and therfore the deletes where shown in the while loop query after deleted... sorry for the noobs approach guys.